# Matrix. Calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

matrix $$U=\begin{bmatrix}
a &b  & c &d  &e \\ 
 f&  j& h & f & a\\ 
 e&r  &t  &g  &n \\ 
 f&  h&  v& b &m \\ 
 e& r & t &y  &n 
\end{bmatrix} $$

what means U(:,1) and U(:,1:3)?

Comment: Please, provide more information about the context of your question. What are you talking about? MatLab?

Answer (score 4):

In Matlab notation, $U(:,1)$ means the first column of $U$.

$U(:,1:3)$ means the submatrix of $U$ that consists of the first $3$ columns.

Answer (score 3):

$U(:,1)$ = first column of $U$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
a &   \\ 
 f&  \\ 
 e&  \\ 
 f&  \\ 
 e& 
\end{bmatrix}
 U(:,1:3) = first three columns of $U$\begin{bmatrix}
a &b  & c  \\ 
 f&  j& h \\ 
 e&r  &t   \\ 
 f&  h&  v\\ 
 e& r & t  
\end{bmatrix}